# rotating jlabel java swing

Tags: java, swing, rotation

i'am using JTransformer class from swinghelper

https://swinghelper.dev.java.net/

when i chose flowlayout there is no problem but if i use null layout i cant see my button
on frame

any help would be appreciated.

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

import org.jdesktop.swinghelper.transformer.JXTransformer;

public class Main {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
private List<JXTransformer> transformers = new ArrayList<JXTransformer>();

private JXTransformer createTransformer(JComponent c) {
    JXTransformer t = new JXTransformer(c);
    transformers.add(t);
    return t;
}

public void fonk() {

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            //f.setLayout(null);

    f.setBounds(500,500,500,500);

    JButton b = new JButton("JButton");
    b.setSize(10,10);
    b.setLocation(10,10);
    f.add(createTransformer(b));


    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.rotate(45 * Math.PI / 180);

    for (JXTransformer t : transformers) {
        t.setTransform(at);
    }

    f.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new Main().fonk();

}
```

}

Comment: Please indent the code by four spaces so it looks right.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it makes a difference but whenever I use the rotate method is just use:

```
g2.rotate( Math.toRadians( 90 ) );
```

Or if you want an alternative approach, instead of rotating the entire component you can just use a [Rotated Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/)

Answer (score 0):

Your button is probably up and to the left of the upper left corner.

set the rotation angle to 45, -45, 135, -135 degrees in order to determine, around which point it is rotating.